# Displaying Operands as Position Independent in IDA

Tags: ida, x86, x86-64, offset, pic

I'm writing an IDA python script, and i need to be able to detect position independent code. I have an instruction that IDA displays using the operand name 'format'

```
lea     rdi, format
```

However, when i use capstone disassembler or disassember.io it displays the instruction as

```
lea     rdi, [rip + 0xd5a]
```

Is there an ida python function that will return the instruction in the form of the register + the immediate offset instead of the relative value or operand name?

I tried using `idc.get_operand_value` but it returns the full address, not the register + offset.

I've also tried `idc.GetDisasm` but that just returns the instruction as it's displayed in IDA.

The hexbytes for the instruction are `48 8d 3d 5a 0d 00 00`

Architecture is `i386 x86-64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options-General-Analysis-Processor specific options, [x] Explicit RIP-addressing.